# How to programmatically login to a site that uses Google as auth

Tags: node.js, authentication, jabbr

I'm currently trying to figure out how to log in to a Jabbr site with a NodeJS that only authenticates with Google accounts.

Is there some simple way to do this? I've tried using the njabbr package but it doesn't currently doesn't support Google authentication. Most of what I've googled was about implementing login on a server and I've looked into [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) but it doesn't make much sense to me when all I want to do is to log in with a client.

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth

Comment: @ChrisCM: I can't see how that helps me. It's examples uses consumer keys and consumer secrets that I cannot provide and applies if you write a web app. I'm only interested in logging in to a service that uses Google, or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I see, what you want is even simpler(that link is actually of the implementing login in a server, variety).  Logins to sites are usually just post requests, containing username and password in some key/value scheme.  It's going to be site dependant though, as the site is what passes the authentication information to google to get the login session.  But ultimately it's just an http request, and you might have to handle a cookie, with some sort of session id.

Comment: @ChrisCM: Looks like I have to do some packet sniffing then. :-)

Comment: Yeah, there are handy libraries for certain google specific functionality(GMail, Calendar, etc), but for logging into a site implementing Google OAuth... you're stuck figuring out their login scheme.